# Can you use water from a municipal supply and return it for home cooling?

Tags: water, cooling

You can make your own solar and back-feed it into the grid and get paid for it (while getting severely ripped off, nonetheless).

Here's my idea: Since water coming from the city supply is ~45-55 degrees, we could technically use that to create a cooling system for the summer without really using any water as long as it can be backfed into the pipes and back to the city after it warms up a couple of degrees. Of course, we'd need a small pump that makes up the difference for local losses):

```
   (Incoming water pressure) 
 + (local losses + refeed losses) 
 + Pump recycling power 
>= incoming water pressure.
```

If you simplify, we'd have to determine how much power we need to make up for the local + refeed losses in terms of watts used by a refeed pump.

Based on my understanding, the $$ spent to refeed the water should be less than the cost saved from the incoming chilled water, since water in = water out.

The only drawback is that we'd need two separate water lines, one to get water, and one to receive it. Now that I think about it, this can totally be achieved with a closed system as long as the water recirculating can have enough length underground to chill again.

Now, you may ask, "But bro, if you keep feeding back warmer water, won't that warm up the entire supply?"

No, as the ground it travels through has tremendous potential energy that can chill the water back. Hence my idea is that a closed system may work as well, though the much higher cost to implement compared to a standalone system.

Food for thought. Let me know what you guys think.

(And yes, I'm aware that heat pumps work in a similar way).

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145186/discussion-on-question-by-techguy-can-you-use-water-from-a-municipal-supply-and); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 14):

Congratulations! You just invented a [geothermal heat pump](https://www.energy.gov/energysaver/geothermal-heat-pumps).

It's like an AC unit, but uses liquid and ground for cooling side instead of less efficient air. At this point you might as well get an actual certified heat pump and skip the part where you mess with city water supply (and risking heavy fines).

In fact, [heat pumps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_pump) are designed to cool/warm the refrigerant much more than the bare ground temperature, making the deal much more efficient.

One useful thing about ground-source heat pumps is that you can use them to warm your house in winter and cool it down in summer--it's a two for price of one deal. If you add some solar panels you have a very cheap cooling and heating most of the year.

Regarding refeeding the water, there are multiple issues with the idea:

1. Water meter. You cannot connect before the water meter, so to have in and out you would need two meters. If you just ask for second meter, it would still come from same supply line, so you would need a property some distance away and connect them with underground pipe. It is quite possible the meters do not work in reverse (or even have a check valve), so you will end up paying for water you did not physically use, or find out the meter acts like a stop and you cannot push anything in no matter how hard you try. At this point you may want to consider evaporative cooling (aka point a sprinkler at yourself).
2. Contamination. Municipal water supply is guaranteed to be potable. By injecting water you may introduce contaminants. The water company will very not like that, and you have no certifications to prove your contraption is "water safe". Have you considered if your pump is potable water certified? There are different pump types.
3. Depending on location, city water supply will have significant pressure. If you try to pump water in, and are in lower part of area, you will find that a pretty powerful pump is needed. There is a reason many homes have 'pressure adjuster thingy' near meter, so the faucets don't turn into fire engine hoses every time you open them.

Answer (score 9):

No, not allowed in 3 countries I am aware of.

The primary reason is controlling contamination.

Then you will have to exceed the mains supply pressure - which in my country is 9 bar. At each point of use there is a pressure reducer.

Answer (score 1):

The excellent answer from Thomas sums up everything well. You cannot do this with the utility water.

On the other hand, the idea is not completely worthless.

There are places with available groundwater that can be used exactly like this - both for cooling and heating, with and without a heatpump.

The general principle goes like this: one digs two wells, separated by some distance and/or aligned with the underground water currents.

In one of them, there is a pump. The water is passed to whatever heat exchanger and then returned to the other well.

This method is used to:

- cool and heat residences (usually with a heatpump, at least for heating, groundwater is usually cold enough to be directly used for cooling)
- dump heat from industrial processes (e.g. power power plants, only with a heat exchanger).
- heating greenhouses. The usual groundwater is hot enough to keep the greenhouse few degrees above freezing in winter and for a lot of greenhouse plants this is "good enough" and almost for free (it is really free when compared to heating the greenhouse by other means).

... and in some places where the groundwater is really, really abundant one could dig only a single well and dump the heated/cooled water in the city drain.

Comment: Most city water treatment would rather not get extra water in their returns, as they have to process it.  Back in the day, storm water was mixed in, and that tends to overwhelm sewage during severe storms.   New plans keep storm water and the like seperate.  Likewise sump discharge is also not allowed.

Comment: @DaveM valid points, when done properly the water is returned in the rain tubes or, in few cases I am familiar with, in the nearby small river.